# Plotting Poisson distribution with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to fit a Poisson distribution to this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyiTv.png) and the way I've been taught to do this is by defining the poisson distribution as a function and then using a linspace to plot the function.

```
def poisson_m(k, l):
return ((l ** k)/math.factorial(k)) * np.exp ** (-l)`

lin = np.linspace(0, 187, 100)
ax.plot(lin, poisson_m(lin, 20), 'r--', label="Poissonverdeling")
```

for now l is just a random guess, but we've been taught to minimise this to find the best fit (which is my ultimate goal in fitting the poisson distribution).
This has worked for me so far but for this function i get the error message

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

I'm not sure what this means in regards to my linspace and function. I've tried to read similar questions but those all used wildly different ways to plot a poisson distribution, so I guess I'd like to know if it's possible to do it this way and get rid of the error somehow, as it would be ideal to do it in a way that follows the instructions I've been given. I know there's a poisson distribution in scipy but I wouldn't know how to use that to find the best fit for l, and seeing as that's the goal, I didn't decide to use that one.

Comment: `math.factorial` is not vectorized, so it won't work on an array. You must use `scipy.special.factorial(k)`. Also `np.exp ** (-l)` is not valid, it's `np.exp(-1)`

Answer (score 1):

The Poisson distribution is a discrete probability distribution, which means you cannot calculate its values when your `lin` contains non-integers. So the first fix would be to replace `linspace` with `arange` for example.

Second issue is `np.exp ** (-l)`, replace this with `np.exp(-l)`.

The error message comes from `math.factorial`. As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.factorial) the `math.factorial` tries to convert its argument into an integer. If it fails (which it does, because you gave it a `numpy.ndarray`), it returns a `ValueError`. So use `scipy.special.factorial` for example, which calculates element-wise factorial.

The complete code would be like this:

```
from scipy.special import factorial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def poisson_m(k, l):
    return ((l ** k)/factorial(k)) * np.exp(-l)

lin = np.arange(0, 187)
plt.plot(lin, poisson_m(lin, 20), 'r--', label="Poissonverdeling")
```

If I were you, I would instead use the `poisson` class from `scipy.stats` module.

```
from scipy.stats import poisson

lin = np.arange(0, 187)
plt.plot(lin, poisson(20).pmf(lin))
```